# Restore Layout does not restore the modules content

Tags: prism, avalondock

i"m using prism with AvalonDoc.

when i try to restore the layout (on the event handler of the menu button "RestoreLayout")

dockManager.RestoreLayout(FileName);

i do get the correct layout structure, but the content of every region is now empty. do i need to reload to modules or something like that ?

the avalondoc code im my  xaml code is something like that:

```
  <ad:ResizingPanel ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="*" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">

   <ad:DockablePane ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeHeight="150" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionDocPane1">

                    <ad:DockableContent Name="DocContent1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

    </ad:DockablePane>

            </ad:ResizingPanel>
```

```
                <ad:DockableContent Name="DocContent2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

```
        </ad:ResizingPanel>

    </ad:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't restore your content because Avalon dock (and most docking mechanisms) don't and can't store your user-controls state.  You need to do this manually.